# SQLAlchemy - how to avoid an error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Here is model column:

```
title = Column(Unicode(100))
```

When I try to add a record to db with cyrillic letters in `title` I get an error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 
>   latin-1' codec can't encode characters on position ...

If i encode it with utf-8

```
title = request.POST['title'].encode('utf-8')
```

I get next error:

> ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit btystrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.

When I decode utf-8

```
title = request.POST['title'].decode('utf-8')
```

There is new error

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters...

What to do?

**EDIT:**

I'm using **Sqlite3**, I thought it may be important.

**EDIT 2: (code and traceback)**

My code:

```
title = request.POST['title']

new_model = Model(
    ...
    title = title,
    ...
)
DBSession.add(new_model)
DBSession.flush()
```

And Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/p/work/SUN/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-0.9.7-py2.6.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/panels/performance.py", line 55, in resource_timer_handler

> result = handler(request)

File "/home/p/work/SUN/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a3-py2.6.egg/pyramid/tweens.py", line 20, in excview_tween

> response = handler(request)

File "/home/p/work/SUN/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid_tm-0.3-py2.6.egg/pyramid_tm/**init**.py", line 61, in tm_tween

> response = handler(request)

File "/home/p/work/SUN/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a3-py2.6.egg/pyramid/router.py", line 164, in handle_request

> response = view_callable(context, request)

File "/home/p/work/SUN/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a3-py2.6.egg/pyramid/config/views.py", line 316, in rendered_view

> result = view(context, request)

File "/home/p/work/SUN/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a3-py2.6.egg/pyramid/config/views.py", line 426, in _requestonly_view

> response = view(request)

File "/home/p/work/SUN/sunviver/sunviver/views/advert.py", line 187, in create

> return HTTPFound(location=new_advert.url())

File "/home/p/work/SUN/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a3-py2.6.egg/pyramid/httpexceptions.py", line 444, in **init**

> body_template=body_template, location=location, **kw)

File "/home/p/work/SUN/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a3-py2.6.egg/pyramid/httpexceptions.py", line 213, in **init**

> Response.**init**(self, status=status, **kw)

File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/webob/response.py", line 141, in **init**

> setattr(self, name, value)

File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/webob/descriptors.py", line 112, in fset

> value = value.encode('latin-1')

And `new_advert.url()`:

```
def url(self):
    return '/%s/%s' % (self.id, self.title.replace(' ', '_'))
```

**@J.F. Sebastian**

**Traceback (most recent call last):**
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 93, in run

> self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a3-py2.6.egg/pyramid/router.py", line 187, in **call**

> response = self.handle_request(request)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-0.9.7-py2.6.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/toolbar.py", line 157, in toolbar_tween

> toolbar.process_response(response)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-0.9.7-py2.6.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/toolbar.py", line 55, in process_response

> vars, request=request)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a3-py2.6.egg/pyramid/renderers.py", line 81, in render

> return helper.render(value, None, request=request)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a3-py2.6.egg/pyramid/renderers.py", line 420, in render

> result = renderer(value, system_values)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a3-py2.6.egg/pyramid/mako_templating.py", line 162, in **call**

> reraise(MakoRenderingException(errtext), None, exc_info[2])

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a3-py2.6.egg/pyramid/mako_templating.py", line 154, in **call**

> result = template.render_unicode(**system)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.5.0-py2.6.egg/mako/template.py", line 311, in render_unicode

> as_unicode=True)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.5.0-py2.6.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 660, in _render

> **_kwargs_for_callable(callable_, data))

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.5.0-py2.6.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 692, in _render_context

> _exec_template(inherit, lclcontext, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.5.0-py2.6.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 718, in _exec_template

> callable_(context, *args, **kwargs)

File "pyramid_debugtoolbar_templates_toolbar_mako", line 117, in render_body

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-0.9.7-py2.6.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/panels/headers.py", line 54, in content

> vars, self.request)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-0.9.7-py2.6.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/panels/**init**.py", line 24, in render

> return render(template_name, vars, request=request)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a3-py2.6.egg/pyramid/renderers.py", line 81, in render

> return helper.render(value, None, request=request)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a3-py2.6.egg/pyramid/renderers.py", line 420, in render

> result = renderer(value, system_values)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a3-py2.6.egg/pyramid/mako_templating.py", line 162, in **call**

> reraise(MakoRenderingException(errtext), None, exc_info[2])

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a3-py2.6.egg/pyramid/mako_templating.py", line 154, in **call**

> result = template.render_unicode(**system)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.5.0-py2.6.egg/mako/template.py", line 311, in render_unicode

> as_unicode=True)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.5.0-py2.6.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 660, in _render

> **_kwargs_for_callable(callable_, data))

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.5.0-py2.6.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 692, in _render_context

> _exec_template(inherit, lclcontext, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.5.0-py2.6.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 718, in _exec_template

> callable_(context, *args, **kwargs)

File "pyramid_debugtoolbar_panels_templates_headers_mako", line 34, in render_body

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MarkupSafe-0.15-py2.6.egg/markupsafe/_native.py", line 21, in escape

> return Markup(unicode(s)

MakoRenderingException:

**Traceback (most recent call last):**

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a3-py2.6.egg/pyramid/mako_templating.py", line 154, in **call**

> result = template.render_unicode(**system)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.5.0-py2.6.egg/mako/template.py", line 311, in render_unicode

> as_unicode=True)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.5.0-py2.6.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 660, in _render

> **_kwargs_for_callable(callable_, data))

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.5.0-py2.6.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 692, in _render_context

> _exec_template(inherit, lclcontext, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.5.0-py2.6.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 718, in _exec_template

> callable_(context, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-0.9.7-py2.6.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/templates/toolbar.mako", line 61, in render_body

> ${panel.content()|n}

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-0.9.7-py2.6.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/panels/headers.py", line 54, in content

> vars, self.request)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-0.9.7-py2.6.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/panels/**init**.py", line 24, in render

> return render(template_name, vars, request=request)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a3-py2.6.egg/pyramid/renderers.py", line 81, in render

> return helper.render(value, None, request=request)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a3-py2.6.egg/pyramid/renderers.py", line 420, in render

> result = renderer(value, system_values)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a3-py2.6.egg/pyramid/mako_templating.py", line 162, in **call**

> reraise(MakoRenderingException(errtext), None, exc_info[2])

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a3-py2.6.egg/pyramid/mako_templating.py", line 154, in **call**

> result = template.render_unicode(**system)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.5.0-py2.6.egg/mako/template.py", line 311, in render_unicode

> as_unicode=True)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.5.0-py2.6.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 660, in _render

> **_kwargs_for_callable(callable_, data))

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.5.0-py2.6.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 692, in _render_context

> _exec_template(inherit, lclcontext, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.5.0-py2.6.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 718, in _exec_template

> callable_(context, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-0.9.7-py2.6.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/panels/templates/headers.mako", line 13, in render_body

> ${value|h}

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MarkupSafe-0.15-py2.6.egg/markupsafe/_native.py", line 21, in escape

> return Markup(unicode(s)

**MakoRenderingException:**

**Traceback (most recent call last):**

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid-1.3a3-py2.6.egg/pyramid/mako_templating.py", line 154, in **call**

> result = template.render_unicode(**system)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.5.0-py2.6.egg/mako/template.py", line 311, in render_unicode

> as_unicode=True)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.5.0-py2.6.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 660, in _render

> **_kwargs_for_callable(callable_, data))

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.5.0-py2.6.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 692, in _render_context

> _exec_template(inherit, lclcontext, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.5.0-py2.6.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 718, in _exec_template

> callable_(context, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-0.9.7-py2.6.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/panels/templates/headers.mako", line 13, in render_body

> ${value|h}

File "/home/ponomar/v/ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MarkupSafe-0.15-py2.6.egg/markupsafe/_native.py", line 21, in escape

> return Markup(unicode(s)

**UnicodeDecodeError:** 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Check that there are no non-ascii characters in `new_advert.url()`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I've added `new_advert.url()` to the bottom of the question

Comment: try `path = '/%s/%s' % (self.id, self.title.replace(' ', '_')); return urllib.quote(path.encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - Didn't help. I think that problem may be in Pyramid framework urls, because I've tried to open any article with cyrillic letters in title and it shows me now `A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.` even in debug mode (without any traceback), but it opens articles without Russian letters. Will search at Pyramid docs. But thanks anyway, you really helped when pointed on urls.

Comment: *"didn't help"* is not very specific. Is it the same error? Show traceback.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - I've updated my questio with new traceback. Starts from `@J.F.Sebastian` and it's really big...

Comment: [format you question to be human readable](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Remove pyramid_debugtoolbar and Create a [complete, minimal example](http://sscce.org/) that shows the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encoding converts Unicode strings to byte strings. You need to go in the other direction,
[decoding](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode): `request.POST['title'].decode('utf-8')` (assuming `request.POST['title']` is a UTF8-encoded `str`).

Comment: Now there is new error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters...`